# Multiple Dropdownlist from another spreadsheet with more than 500 items in each

Tags: list, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

Hello and thanks in advance for your help,

I find many other topics about this, but I did not find answers to my problem, so here I am.

My goal is to automaticly create dropdow lists in a board (between 50-100 drop down list), according to a word in another column. The data should be in another spreadsheet, and most of the dropdown list could go around 600-700 items.
Please check in picture below for more explainations :

[board picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zur8Y.jpg)
The dropdown list 1 and 2 are created in column G and H if it does find a sheet name in the first word of the column F "designation". If you pick an item of colum G "Libellés", it makes a Vlookup for column "MP" and price in the designated sheet. Same if you pick an item in of column "MP", it makes a Vlookup in "Libellés" and "price" to match.

This is working fine when all sheets are in the same spreadsheet, but I can't find a way to make it work when all data sheets are in another spreadsheet. The spreadsheet with the code will be copy many times (200+ each year), so I want to put the database sheets (15000+lignes x 5 columns) in only one spreadsheet that feeds all others "small" spreadsheets when we open those.

I tryed many options :

- requireValueInList : This is not working, some lists are 600-700 items, not working with big lists like this.
- list from a range : Ranges are too big, and I have around 50-100 dropdown list of 100-700 items, this is too much, program stops before the end (and I have a good computer, which is not the case of most of my colleagues), so this is not a solution, or I am doing it wrong.
- **requireValueInRange : This is what I am using to make it run when everything is on the same spreadsheet, but can't use it if datas are on another spreadsheet.**

Is there a way to get around requireValueInRange limitation? This is the first time I use google app script so please don't judge too harshly.

here is the code, it is working fine when all data sheets are in the same sspreadsheet as the target sheet for drop dow list:

```
 function onOpen(e) {
     
  // sss for source spreadsheet where I have all datas, and tss for target spreadsheet where I want my lists to be created
  var sss1 = spreadsheetApp.openById('blahblah');
  var ssh1 = sss1.getSheetByName('Emballages');
 
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsh = tss.getActiveSheet();
  var tsh1 = tss.getSheetByName('Fiche_eclate_CS');

     
// The below part is to update 2 lists, using datas from the sheet "emballages" in the source spreadsheet, all working fine except data validation rule, won't accept arguments
   
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0]; 
  var column = sheet.getRange("F:F").getValues();
  var prow;
   for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
    if (column[i][0] === "Packaging :") {
      prow = i+1;
      break;     
     }
    }
      
   var emblrow = ssh1.getRange('B:B').getLastRow();
  
       var cel1D = tsh1.getRange(prow,7);
// This is where I have problems. The call ('B2:B'+ emblrow) is not accepted. I can't use this as data validation on another spreadsheet.
       var cel2D = ssh1.getRange('B2:B'+ emblrow); 
       var ruleD = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(cel2D).build();
       cel1D.setDataValidation(ruleD);
   
   var cel1M = tsh1.getRange(prow,8);
// Same problem here. The call ('A2:A'+ emblrow) is not accepted.  
   var cel2M = ssh1.getRange('A2:A'+ emblrow ); 
   var ruleM = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(cel2M).build();
   cel1M.setDataValidation(ruleM);
     

 // The below part is to update many lists, using datas from one sheet in the source spreadsheet. To find the good sheet in the other spreadsheet, I use the split function. This part is working fine. I only have problems with data validation rules, same as above.
   
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();     
   var button = ui.alert("Voulez vous mettre à jour toutes les listes de la feuille ?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
   
   if (button == ui.Button.YES) {
   
   
  var anchhrow;
  var anchbrow;
  var column1 = tsh1.getRange("B:B").getValues();

   for (var i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
    if (column1[i][0] === "Anchor-haut") {
      anchhrow = i+3;
      break;     
     }
    } 
    
   for (var i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
    if (column1[i][0] === "Anchor-bas") {
      anchbrow = i;
      break;     
     }
    }
   
   var rangeH1 = tsh.getRange('H'+anchhrow +':H'+anchbrow).getValues();
   var range = tsh.getRange('H'+anchhrow +':H'+anchbrow);
   var lrowH = rangeH1.length; 

   for (var k=0; k<lrowH; k++){
   
     var rown = anchhrow + k;
     var testrng = sheet.getRange("F" + rown);     
     
     if ( testrng == "" ) {
     }
     else {
       
       var name = nom(tsh,rown);                       
       var ssh3 = sss1.getSheetByName(name);
       
       if (ssh3 == null){
       }
         else {
           
           var flrow = ssh3.getRange('B2:B').getLastRow();
     


            var rng1D = tsh1.getRange(k+anchhrow,7);
// same issu, can't use ('B2:B'+ flrow)for data validation 
            var rng2D = ssh3.getRange('B2:B'+ flrow); 
            var ruleD = 

SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rng2D).build();
               rng1D.setDataValidation(ruleD);
       
   
               var rng1M = tsh1.getRange(k+anchhrow,8);
// same here, can't use ('A2:A'+ flrow)for data validation 
               var rng2M = ssh3.getRange('A2:A'+ flrow ); 
               var ruleM = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rng2M).build();
               rng1M.setDataValidation(ruleM);  
                 
           }
      }

  }

     function nom(sheet,row){
       var word = [{}]; 
       var rng = sheet.getRange("F" + row);
       var word = rng.getValue().split(" ");
       Logger.log(word);
       return word[0];       
     }   
   }
  else {
  }   
   
// This part is where I control prices once all lists are updated, this is working fine.   
   
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();     
   var button = ui.alert("Les listes ont été mises à jour. Voulez vous mettre à jour les prix ?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
   
   if (button == ui.Button.YES) {
     
     for(var j=0;j<lrowH; j++){     
   
       var cellI1 = tsh.getRange(j+anchhrow,8).getValue(); 
  
       if (cellI1 == "") {
        }
       else {
         var cellI2 = vlookup(ssh2,1,3,cellI1);   
         tsh.getRange(j+anchhrow,9).setValue(cellI2);

    
    function vlookup(sheet, column, index, value) {

      var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
      var data=sheet.getRange(1,column,lastRow,column+index).getValues();
    
      for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
        if (data[i][0]==value){
          return data[i][index];             
        }
      }
    }
   }
  } 
 }
  else {
  }
  Browser.msgBox ("MAJ feuille terminée");
}
```

Feel free to ask questions if there are stuffs you don't understand or if you need more details.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly is not working if you use another spreadsheet? Would you mind providing more details? @mat

Comment: Hello, I can't use "blahblah!B2:B" to create list if "blahblah" sheet is in another spreadsheet. You encounter the same problem if you try to create a drop down list manualy, you can't select range from another spreadsheet with "list from a range".The only way I found to make those lists is to use "requireValueInList". this is the same as making a data validation with a "list of item", but with hundreds of items, the program stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you are encountering is due to the fact that you are calling the `getActiveSpreadsheet` method instead of the `openById(id)`.

However, assuming that you have the same names for the sheets but they're just in different spreadsheets and you want to keep on using the `requireValueInRange` method, I suggest you add the following lines to your code:

#### Code

```
function createDataValidation() {
  let spreadsheetIds = ['SS_1_ID', 'SS_2_ID', ...];
  for (let i=0; i<spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);
    var tsh = tss.getActiveSheet();
    var tsh1 = tss.getSheetByName('Fiche_eclate_CS');
    // the rest of your code
  }
}
```

The code above is looping through all the spreadsheets - this is done by storing all the ids of the spreadsheets you want to use in the `spreadsheetIds` variable and afterwards, by using a `for` loop, is accessing each one of them and using the code you already have.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feeback. I think I was not very clear in my post, so I updated the code to put the one that is not working when I target other spreadsheets. I put // to guide and show where problem is. I have no issues calling other spreadsheets, but I am having troubles with the data validation rule, as I can't use "list from a range" when datas are not in the same spreadsheet.  The error is telling "the argument 'blahblah'B2:B from data validation rule is not valide". Other topics talk about this, but the solution is not working as my lists are too big. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does the 'blahblah' sheet exist in the other spreadsheet?

Comment: Maybe you need to break up your large lists into ranges. A-J / K-R / S-Z sort of thing

Comment: Sorry its confusing, I used 'blahblah' to refer as a sheet and a spreadsheet. We can say 'blahblah' is the data spreadsheet. In this spreadsheet, I have 9 sheets. All those sheets are automactly updates with references of products, prices and other infos. I can't really split items into more sheets, as this is won't make any sens to classify them. On my other spreadsheet, I have only one sheet, 'Fiche_eclate_CS', which will contains all the lists. Sheet 'Fiche_eclate_CS' is not inside 'blahblah' spreadsheet.

Comment: Then in order to access each sheet from the different spreadsheets, you should open each spreadsheet using the `openById`, get its name and based on that get the necessary sheet in order to perform the tasks wanted. @mat

Comment: Hello, I do this with the split function.                                                       
  function nom(sheet,row){  
       var word = [{}];   
       var rng = sheet.getRange("F" + row);
       var word = rng.getValue().split(" ");
       Logger.log(word);
       return word[0];       
     }   
   }

Comment: I Return word and use it to access a specific spreadsheet with this name               
  var name = nom(tsh,rown);                                                                                     
  var ssh3 = sss1.getSheetByName(name);                                                             the sss1 spreadsheet is my data spreadsheet, and ssh3 is the sheet of this spreadsheet where i need to take data from

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand the issue you are having. So essentially if you get the right spreadsheet and its sheets, what is not working?

Comment: I have an error, telling " "blahblah!B2:B is not a valide argument to make the data validation rule". I guess this is because I can't create lists from another spreadsheet with this method. Other topics propose to put all the items directly in the lists with a range (requireValueInList) to avoid the link issue, but this is not workable in my case.

Comment: Hi, to give you more info, you can check in this topic, this is exactly the same issu. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987051/spreadsheet-script-validation-the-data-validation-rule-argument-employeesb1) .However, The spreadsheet with lists will be copied hundreds of time every year. So I don't want to import all datas (15000rows on 5 columns) everytime I make a new one. Is it possible to load datas when sheet is open and then unload when sheet is closed, on loacked sheets for example.

Comment: Yes, but if you load each spreadsheet and then use the correct sheet name for each spreadsheet, you will be able to successfully execute the code above.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code to make it on one spreadsheet. All sheets of the data base spreadsheet are imported with "importrange" into sheets in the target spreadsheet. Code is working fine in this case, because everything is in the same spreadsheet. However, this represent a lot of datas stored for no reason everytime the spreadsheet is copied, this is what I wanted to avoid. Anyway, thanks for the help and this will do the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
function betweenSpreadsheets() {
  let localSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  let distSsUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H-Zh blah blah KHP7x8/edit?usp=sharing'; 
  let distSsId = '1H-Zh blah blah KHP7x8';
  let distSs1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(distSsId)
  let distSs2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(distSsUrl)
  
}
```

Then proceed as if the sheets were in the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter, that validate answer before I could finish. Hello, thanks you for the quick answer. This is where I have a problem, when I declare another spreadsheet, with URL or ID, I got an error telling that the argument of the validation rule is not OK. I can't use "blahblah!B2:B" to create list, if blahblah is in another spreadsheet. Is it the "let" that is solving the issu?